# Howto generate classes from WSDL and XSD with gradle, equivalent to maven-jaxb2-plugin

Tags: java, maven, wsdl, gradle, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I want to switch my Maven2 build file to gradle.
Generating the java classes from WSDL + XSDs with gradle seems to be not documented further there is no gradle plugin for this.
I use the following configuration with maven and search the equivalent for gradle.

```
<!-- plugin for generating the classes from the WSDL+XSD -->
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.7.3</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>app1-stub-generation</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>generate</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <schemaDirectory>${project.build.directory}/wsdl/app1</schemaDirectory>
        <schemaIncludes>
          <include>*.xsd</include>
        </schemaIncludes>
        <generatePackage>org.app1.ws.generated</generatePackage>
        <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/app1</generateDirectory>
        <strict>true</strict>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>app2-v1-stub-generation</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>generate</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
        <schemaIncludes>
          <include>v1/*.xsd</include>
        </schemaIncludes>
        <generatePackage>org.app2.ws.generated.v1</generatePackage>
        <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/v1</generateDirectory>
        <strict>true</strict>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>app2-v2-stub-generation</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>generate</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
        <schemaIncludes>
          <include>v2/*.xsd</include>
        </schemaIncludes>
        <generatePackage>org.app2.ws.generated.v2</generatePackage>
        <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/v2</generateDirectory>
        <strict>true</strict>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

i solved it...

```
configurations {
    jaxb
}

dependencies {
    jaxb group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-xjc', version: '2.2.4-1'
}

task jaxb () {
    // output directory
    jaxbTargetDir = file( "${buildDir}/generated-sources" )
    jaxbTargetDirV19 = file( jaxbTargetDir.path + '/v19' )
    jaxbTargetDirV110 = file( jaxbTargetDir.path + '/v110' )
    jaxbTargetDirOtherWs = file( jaxbTargetDir.path + '/otherWs' )

    // perform actions
    doLast {
        jaxbTargetDirV19.mkdirs()
        jaxbTargetDirV110.mkdirs()
        jaxbTargetDirOtherWs.mkdirs()

        ant.taskdef(name: 'xjc', classname: 'com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask', classpath: configurations.jaxb.asPath)
        ant.jaxbTargetDirV19 = jaxbTargetDirV19
        ant.jaxbTargetDirV110 = jaxbTargetDirV110
        ant.jaxbTargetDirOtherWs = jaxbTargetDirOtherWs

        // My-Webservice v1.10
        ant.xjc(
                destdir: '${jaxbTargetDirV110}',
                package: 'mypackage.ws.generated.v110',
                schema: 'src/main/resources/wsdl/v1.10/MyServiceSchema.xsd'
        )

        // My-Webservice v1.9
        ant.xjc(
                destdir: '${jaxbTargetDirV19}',
                package: 'mypackage.ws.generated.v19',
                schema: 'src/main/resources/wsdl/v1.9/MyServiceSchema.xsd'
        )

        // OtherWs-Webservice
        ant.xjc(
                destdir: '${jaxbTargetDirOtherWs}',
                package: 'mypackage.otherws.generated',
                schema: 'src/main/resources/wsdl/OtherWsServiceSchema.xsd'
        )
    }
}
compileJava.dependsOn jaxb
```

Comment: If anyone is still tracking this, has anyone tried to add JAXB extensions to this? When I do this, I get an error like "Provider xx not a subtype", where "xx" is the main plugin class for the extension.

Answer (score 13):

If you can't find a Gradle plugin for a particular need (and don't want to write your own plugin), look out for an Ant task. Here is one for JAXB: [XJC Ant Task](http://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.0.2/docs/xjcTask.html).

Any Ant task can be used as-is from Gradle (see [Using Ant from Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/ant.html)). In the future, Gradle will also support the execution of Maven plugins.

Answer (score 6):

Use the plugin as described here: https://github.com/nilsmagnus/wsdl2java

Note: as of 2020, this advice is no longer applicable, as the recommended plugin has been discontinued and no longer works with newer versions of Gradle.

Comment: There is an actively maintained version of that plugin here: https://github.com/bjornvester/wsdl2java-gradle-plugin