# How to generate artifacts from WSDL and XSD using gradle?

Tags: jakarta-ee, gradle, build.gradle

Can you post sample code to generate artifacts from wsdl and xsd using gradle? Also are there any in built plugins available? Also how can we load custom binding files using gradle?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a similar question that has been answered: [Howto generate classes from WSDL and XSD with gradle, equivalent to maven-jaxb2-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8158453/howto-generate-classes-from-wsdl-and-xsd-with-gradle-equivalent-to-maven-jaxb2)

A blog article: http://joerglenhard.wordpress.com/2012/01/10/xjc-and-schemagen-with-gradle/

You can specify a bindings file with `binding: 'your-file-here'`

Answer (score 3):

I am the author of a wsdl2java plugin for gradle. It is open source and easy to use.

https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/no.nils.wsdl2java

Good luck.