# How to generate java classes from wsdl using gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, ant, wsdl, build.gradle

I am new to gradle and working on a project where i have to generate classes from WSDL for using them in webservices.

Found many solutions for generating classes from xsd

[Howto generate classes from WSDL and XSD with gradle, equivalent to maven-jaxb2-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8158453/howto-generate-classes-from-wsdl-and-xsd-with-gradle-equivalent-to-maven-jaxb2)

But i didnt find any way to generate classes from wsdl without using custom plugin.

The same functionality can be implemented using ant very easily :

```
<target name="generate-from-wsdl">
<wsdlc type="JAXWS" destImplDir="output/impl" destJwsDir=" build/output/compiledWsdl" srcWsdl="provides/ProcessFile.wsdl"
</target>
```

Please help me with some pointer to implement the same functionality using Gradle.